# kivy image collider size way too big

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

**What I tried to do:**

I wanted my program to print a message when it collides with the sprite in the middle.

**Problem:**

It doesn't stop printing that it collided. I looked into it with pdb and it says that the Player Sprite is the size of the whole screen, which is weird because I set the image size to 32px by 32px.

What it looks like

[image]

**Code and Sprites mentioned**

Link to mentioned block

[image]

Link to mentioned sprite

[image]

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock
import random
import time
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


#############################################################################

class Collider(Image):
    pass

#############################################################################

root = FloatLayout()

class GameScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(GameScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.wimg = Basic(size = (32,32), source='sprite.png', pos=(270,-120))
        self.block = Collider(size = (32,32), source = 'block.png')


    def playy(self):
        root.add_widget(self.wimg)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.wimg.update, 1.0 / 60.0)

    def worldgen1(self):
        self.add_widget(root)
        root.add_widget(self.block)

    def on_enter(self):
        self.worldgen1()
        self.playy()

#############################################################################

class Basic(Image):

    pFrame = 0

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Basic, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(None, self)
        if not self._keyboard:
            return
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self.on_keyboard_down)

    def on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        if keycode[1] == 'left':
            self.x -= 10
        elif keycode[1] == 'right':
            self.x += 10
        elif keycode[1] == 'up':
            self.y += 10
        elif keycode[1] == 'down':
            self.y -= 10
        else:
            return False
        return True

    def update(self, dt):
        self.pFrame += 1
        if self.parent.parent.block.collide_widget(self.parent.parent.wimg):
            print ("collide with", self.parent.parent.block)

#############################################################################

class MeinApp(App):

    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(GameScreen(name='gameplay'))
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MeinApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the problem is that `FloatLayout` uses the size_hint to set the size of the widget when it is added, since it does not set it, they take the value of `(1, 1)`, that is, the size of the window.

The solution is to set `size_hint` to `(None, None)`, in addition to using `allow_stretch` in `True` and `keep_ratio` in `False`. In the code I have set the block `pos_hint` to `(0.5, 0.5)` and it will anchor it to that position so it will not move, if you want it to be able to move you must set the `pos`, not the `pos_hint`.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock
import random
import time
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


#############################################################################

class Collider(Image):
    pass

#############################################################################

root = FloatLayout()

class GameScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(GameScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.wimg = Basic(size = (32,32), pos=(200, 100), source='sprite.png', size_hint=(None, None), allow_stretch=True, keep_ratio=False)
        self.block = Collider(size = (32,32), pos_hint={'x': 0.5, 'y':0.5}, source = 'block.png', size_hint=(None, None), allow_stretch=True, keep_ratio=False)

    def playy(self):
        root.add_widget(self.wimg)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.wimg.update, 1.0 / 60.0)

    def worldgen1(self):
        self.add_widget(root)
        root.add_widget(self.block)

    def on_enter(self):
        self.worldgen1()
        self.playy()

#############################################################################

class Basic(Image):

    pFrame = 0

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Basic, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(None, self)
        if not self._keyboard:
            return
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self.on_keyboard_down)

    def on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        if keycode[1] == 'left':
            self.x -= 10
        elif keycode[1] == 'right':
            self.x += 10
        elif keycode[1] == 'up':
            self.y += 10
        elif keycode[1] == 'down':
            self.y -= 10
        else:
            return False
        return True

    def update(self, dt):
        self.pFrame += 1
        if self.parent.parent.block.collide_widget(self.parent.parent.wimg):
            print ("collide with", self.parent.parent.block)

#############################################################################

class MeinApp(App):

    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(GameScreen(name='gameplay'))
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MeinApp().run()
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation it helped a lot! Does the RelativeLayout handle size and pos the same way or is it any different?